# Is there a way to set test timeout value dynamically

Tags: unit-testing, go

Currently I am using the following command for running my test with timeout value given during test call.

> go test myModule -run TestSanity -v --race `-timeout 10h`

Is there a way in Golang testing module to set it during program execution.
Something like,

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    // customTimeout = "10h"
    // m.Timeout(customTimeout)   <--- Something like this
    code := m.Run()
    os.Exit(code)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write your own function to do that:

```
func panicOnTimeout(d time.Duration) {
    <-time.After(d)
    panic("Test timed out")
}

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    go panicOnTimeout(10 * time.Hour) // custom timeout

    code := m.Run()
    os.Exit(code)
}
```

This should simulate what `go test -timeout` does. Be sure to pass `-timeout 0` to prevent the default test timeout from triggering though.

Comment: This forces a panic after a certain time.  But it doesn't extend the standard timeout so it will likely never be called since the standard timeout will "ring" before this does.